# JPA Inheritance strategy JOINED - OneToOne relation in child class - why it doesn't work?

Tags: jpa, inheritance, jakarta-ee, one-to-one

I have 3 tables represented by JPA model.

First one:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "DECISION")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public abstract class Decision {
    @Id
    private Long id;
}
```

Next class extends Decision:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SPECIFIC_DECISION")
public class SpecificDecision extends Decision {
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "PERSON_ID")
    private Person person;
}
```

The last one is Person and it's just simple entity class with person info.

Now when I try to select all decisions from database I get an error with information that the persistence unit is inconsistent with the database schema, because column DECISION.PERSON_ID does not exist, while I do have it in SPECIFIC_DECISION table and that's how I mapped it in JPA model.

What's more interesting if there's no relations in SpecificDecision, only simple NUMBER and VARCHAR fields then everything works fine.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you please past the relavent stacktrace. Its most often alot easier to help you then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there's a solution to my problem. JPA looks for joined columns in base table by default. To change this behaviour an attribute "table" in JoinColumn annotation is needed:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SPECIFIC_DECISION")
public class SpecificDecision extends Decision {
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(table = "SPECIFIC_DECISION", name = "PERSON_ID")
    private Person person;
}
```

Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

You dont have a DiscriminatorColumn defined, im not sure that´s whats causing your problem but according to the JPA specification you always should use discriminator when using a JOINED strategy even though some providers support that you dont. [Link for more info about discriminator](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Inheritance)

Comment: It's not the case, because the mechanism works fine if there's no relation in SpecificDecision.

Comment: I've checked (implemented DisciriminatorColumn) to be sure and I can confirm that the problem is not caused by the lack of discriminator column.